# Ajax/Jquery communicating with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am completely new to Ajax (Jquery POST), and I wrote this thing to try to "talk" to a .php file:

```
function send(d){
    $.post("http://somesite.net/read.php",{data:d})
    .done(function(data){
        document.getElementById('res').innerHTML=data;
    });
}
```

**Read.php:**

```
$d=$_POST["d"];
echo $d;
```

So, it does return stuff, but it seems like it returns the entire file. It is very likely I am doing something incredibly wrong. I would like to know what it is.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by entire file? What else is your output and what is your expected output?

Comment: Expected output: the data sent to the function; Output: entire code. (E.g, if you click "Show source", it shows literally a whole page in the `res` div.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
$d=$_POST["data"];
echo $d;
```

See this line:

```
{data:d}
```

You are sending variable **data** with a value **d**. So in your backend, you should request for variable name.

Comment: Yep :) glad that i could help, please tick my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("http://somesite.net/read.php",{data:d})
```

You have given a full url, but for the security purpose **this is NOT ALLOWED**

use `$.post("./read.php",{data:d})` instead of `$.post("http://somesite.net/read.php",{data:d})`